# Как создать и установить службу Windows при помощи WinApi на C/C++

Tags: winapi, c, c++

У меня есть задача создать службу Windows при помощи WinApi и ее установщик на C/C++.
Это должен быть Win32-проект. Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь прольет свет в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Служебные приложения Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y817hyb6.aspx)
- [Создание своего Windows Service](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/71533/)
- [Создание службы Windows с помощью программы sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192/ru)
- [A Windows Service Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Sund_WindowService.aspx)

Google лучше всех проливает свет. )

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Answer (score 2):

А мне нравится вот [эта статья](http://www.computerra.ru/print/7494/). По ней и писал свои первые службы..

Если собираетесь создавать интерактивные службы, советую обратить внимание, что, начиная с Windows Vista, службам запрещено взаимодействие с рабочим столом - поэтому никаких MessageBox, DialogBox и прочего в собственно службе быть не должно. Так что придется писать отдельное приложение, каким-либо образом подключаться к службе (например, используя TCP/IP) и дальше по задуманному...

Comment: Существуют ли какие-то другие способы кроме TCP/IP, оно каким-то сложным мне показалось :)